# Calculating intersection of rectangles

Tags: c, geometry

Im trying to create a program that takes in 4 values (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) for 2 rectangles, then calculate the (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) of the rectangle created by the two rectangles. Basically the only part I'm having trouble is with the intersection part.

EDIT: Clarifying, It gives me an answer, it is just not the right answer. Punching in 1 1 4 4 and 2 2 5 5 gives me (1,1) (5,5), not the (2,2) (4,4) Im supposed to get.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readRect(int *xmin, int *ymin, int *xmax, int *ymax);
int maxInt(int *val1, int *val2);
int minInt(int *val1, int *val2);

int main(){
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int a,b,c,d;
int xmin1, ymin1, xmax1, ymax1;
int xmin2, ymin2, xmax2, ymax2;


for(;;){
printf(">>enter two rectangles:\n");
x = readRect(&xmin1, &ymin1, &xmax1, &ymax1);
y = readRect(&xmin2, &ymin2, &xmax2, &ymax2);
    if (y == x){
        if (x != 4){
            break;
        }else {
            printf("Rectangle 1: (%d, %d) (%d, %d)\n", xmin1, ymin1, xmax1, ymax1);
            printf("Rectangle 2: (%d, %d) (%d, %d)\n", xmin2, ymin2, xmax2, ymax2);
        }
        a = maxInt(&xmin1, &xmin2);
        b = minInt(&xmax1, &xmax2);
        c = maxInt(&ymin1, &ymin2);
        d = minInt(&ymax1, &ymax2);
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a,b,c,d);
        if ((a < b) && (c < d)) {
            printf("Intersection rectangle: (%d,%d)(%d,%d)\n", a,c,b,d);
        } else {
            printf("These two rectangles do not intersect\n");
        }
    }

}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int readRect(int *xmin, int *ymin, int *xmax, int *ymax){
int noItemsRead;
fflush(stdout);
noItemsRead = scanf("%d %d %d %d", xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);

return noItemsRead;
}

int minInt(int *val1, int *val2){
if (val1 < val2){
    return *val1;
} else {
    return *val2;
}

}

int maxInt(int *val1, int *val2){
if (val1 > val2){
    return *val1;
} else {
    return *val2;
}
}
```

Comment: This is homework question !

Comment: `Basically the only part I'm having trouble is with the intersection part.` What is problem?

Comment: Doesnt give the correct values. If I input 1 1 4 4, then 2 2 5 5, I get (1 1) (5 5). Right answer is (2 2) (4 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thing is fine except your functions `maxInt` and `minInt`. Replace `if (val1 < val2)` by `if (*val1 < *val2)` and `if (val1 > val2)` to `if (*val1 > *val2)`

```
int minInt(int *val1, int *val2){
    if (*val1 < *val2){
        return *val1;
    } 
    else {
        return *val2;
    }

}

int maxInt(int *val1, int *val2){
     if (*val1 > *val2){
         return *val1;
     } 
    else {
         return *val2;
}
```

Comment: I effectively have that, I have just used a, b, c, d to make it easier on the eyes. Changing that line still yields the same wrong answer. Punching in 1 1 4 4, 2 2 5 5 yields (1,1) (5,5) as opposed to the correct answer, which is (2,2) (4,4).

Comment: Ya, just caught this! Thanks. Pointer problems.

Comment: I answered same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19353303/2455888) yesterday!. Do you guys have same assignment?

Comment: Haha, creeped the guy and he has some other questions from the same assignments as me. Seems like they're definetly in my first year CompuSci course! Small world :). Thanks for the help haccks.

Comment: While this fixes the problem, it seems a trifle pointless to be passing the values by pointer in the first place. It would be better to revise the function to `int maxInt(int val1, int val2) { return (val1 > val2) ? val1 : val2; }` (possibly qualified with `static inline` and defined like this in place of the prototype declaration).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; OP wanted to pass pointer rather than values itself :)

Comment: The comment was aimed half at the OP ("you don't need to use pointers") and half at you ("by all means show the code using pointers, but do recommend not using pointers when they are unnecessary", maybe with some guidelines on when they are a good idea — large structures, etc.).  It's a suggested addition to the answer.  Anyway, the point is now discussed in comments; it doesn't need further battering.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my problem, it happens in the following lines, if I change:

```
int minInt(int *val1, int *val2){
if (val1 < val2){
    return *val1;
} else {
    return *val2;
}

}

int maxInt(int *val1, int *val2){
if (val1 > val2){
    return *val1;
} else {
    return *val2;
}
}
```

TO

```
int minInt(int *val1, int *val2){
if (*val1 < *val2){
    return *val1;
} else {
    return *val2;
}

}

int maxInt(int *val1, int *val2){
if (*val1 > *val2){
    return *val1;
} else {
    return *val2;
    }
}
```

Had to add the points when doing the logical comparison.